# BootStrap Mobile Nav Formatting Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have text next to a hyperlink that need to be on the same line in the footer. It works perfectly when responsive doesn't kick into mobile mode.

I have all of the code in `navbar-header`, the `inline-block` works just fine until mobile.

What am I doing wrong?

Footer HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class='navbar-text' style='margin-left: 15px;'>Test - 426482 - Demo</div>        <ul class='nav navbar-nav'><li style='display: inline-block;'><a href='console.php' target='_blank'>Console</a></li></ul>
            </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
          </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <div class='form-group'>
            <form action='logout.php' method='post' class='navbar-form ajaxform'>
              <input type='text' name='fullUrl' hidden='true' id='fullUrl' value="">
              <input type="submit" style="clear: left; width: 100%;" class='btn btn-primary'  name="commit" value="Logout" />
            </form>
          </div>
                  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Footer Normal Version (formatted correctly):
[image]

Footer Mobile Version (need same line):
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `navbar-right` class adds a `float: right` which breaks the display styling. Then Console moves itself to the next line.

Comment: Console isn't wrapped in navbar-right :(

Comment: Correct, but your collapsed navbar does: `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`. So it floats right, bringing it out of `display-inline` and the Console gets placed beneath it.

Comment: Oh, you're right! so what's the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget what I mentioned above. If you use the `navbar-brand` class on your "Test - 426482 - Demo" and "Console" it is much easier to achieve what you want. Take a look at the demo I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zJK8a/).

EDIT: Updated link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zJK8a/2/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <span class="navbar-text" style="float: left;">Test - 426482 - Demo</span>
        <a class="navbar-text" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;" href="console.php" target="_blank">Console</a>
            </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
          </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <div class='form-group'>
            <form action='logout.php' method='post' class='navbar-form ajaxform'>
              <input type='text' name='fullUrl' hidden='true' id='fullUrl' value="">
              <input type="submit" style="clear: left; width: 100%;" class='btn btn-primary'  name="commit" value="Logout" />
            </form>
          </div>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed the same line issue although now the text is huge and I don't want the Test - 426482 - Demo to highlight at all.

Comment: Sorry about that, you had the correct class on your Test - 426482. I updated my answer with a new demo.